# /sys/devices/virtual/gpio dissapears after installing RPi.GPIO on Archlinux ARM

Tags: gpio, archlinux, rpi.gpio, pip

...tinkered a bit with GPIO and Piface Digital. It was all ok until I had installed RPi.GPIO via pip. After that the directory /sys/devices/virtual/gpio disappeared and never showed up again. I had it working earlier when I installed RPi.GPIO from tar.gz.

Yesterday I made a fresh install, and there was that directory. But again, after installing RPi.GPIO over pip it disappeared again.  I have removed that package, rebooted several times, deatached the Piface Digital but no luck. Don't know, what else I can do except reimaging.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As suggested by joan's answer, the gpio sysfs folder is at `/sys/class`. In my current Arch Linux it is that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's not because you have a recent kernel?  I.e. have you recently updated the firmware.

The gpio directory seems to have moved to /sys/class.

```
ls /sys/devices/virtual

bdi    graphics  mem   net  thermal  vc      vchiq   vtconsole
block  input     misc  raw  tty      vc-cma  vc-mem  workqueue
```

.

```
ls /sys/class

bdi          ieee80211         lirc          rtc          uio
block        input             mem           scsi_device  vc
bsg          iscsi_connection  misc          scsi_disk    vc-cma
dma          iscsi_endpoint    mmc_host      scsi_host    vchiq
gpio         iscsi_host        net           sound        vc-mem
graphics     iscsi_iface       power_supply  spidev       vtconsole
hidraw       iscsi_session     raw           spi_master
i2c-adapter  iscsi_transport   rc            thermal
i2c-dev      leds              rfkill        tty
```

Comment: yeah, it'll be so. I do my Syu nearly daily. But that is not simply a move. The /sys/class directory existet formerly and also exists in raspbian, just the created interfaces are showing up in the virtual/gpio directory. But the realization of that didn't help me much since the pifacedigitalio package looked in the wrong directory. So I have modded the interrupts.py file in the pifacecommon package. I changed line 18 to

 `GPIO_INTERRUPT_DEVICE = "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d" % GPIO_INTERRUPT_PIN`

That works for me! :-) Thanx

Answer (score 0):

As @joan listed, the gpio symbolic links in /sys/class/gpio/ moved from /sys/devices/virtual/ to /sys/devices/soc/20200000.gpio.

#### Solution 1

```
chmod -R +x /sys/devices/soc/20200000.gpio
```

#### Solution 2

Update the RPi.GPIO from `/sys/devices/virtual/gpio` to `/sys/class/gpio`.

#### Solution 3

Add line `device_tree=` in `/boot/config.txt`. That will revert the links to be in the old path.
Make sure you reboot after changing the `config.txt`.

---

Pick your flavor :)

### Edit:

I've fixed both [**pi-gpio**](https://github.com/rakeshpai/pi-gpio) ([pull request #34](https://github.com/rakeshpai/pi-gpio/pull/34)) and [**gpio-admin**](https://github.com/quick2wire/quick2wire-gpio-admin) ([pull request #7](https://github.com/quick2wire/quick2wire-gpio-admin/pull/7)) in a manner so that both the old and the new paths are supported. Hopefully, those pull requests are merged soon...